# Limit Windows accounts for a specific IP only?

Tags: windows, active-directory

Is it possible to restrict a Windows AD account to only login from specific ips, using a non third party tool?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can use Windows Firewall with Advanced Security to block access to AD to only specifically allowed subnets or IPs.